# generic function where generic type is any interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'd like do implement a generic function with the generic constraint that the Type passed in is an interface.  Is this possible in C#?  I have it working fine without the constraint, but the code will fail at runtime if it is not an interface, so I'd like to have the compile time checking.

```
public T MyFunction<T> where T : {any interface type} { return null; }
```

Comment: I'm curious as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: How are you making code that fails at runtime if the object doesn't implement any interfaces?

Comment: it's a classed named InterfaceLoader which has one public static method.  It takes a path, spins through it to find all the assemblies in that path which have a type which implements the interface specified in the generic.  Then it creates an instance via the parameterless constructor and passes back an IEnumerable<T> of the generic type specified.

works fine without the constraint, but I would have liked the compile time check also.

Comment: example usage is like this.  IEnumerable<InterfaceTest1.ITestInterface> o = InterfaceLoader<InterfaceTest1.ITestInterface>.Load(@"Z:\PlugInLoader");

Comment: @gbogumil: I just added some code to my answer - in this case, I'd do a runtime check and raise an appropriate exception...

Comment: @Reed - if it is not an interface then the return value will always have 0 instances.  This is because I'm specifically checking the types in the assembly to see if they have an interface that matches the T specified.  If T is not an interface the check will always fail.

Comment: @gbogumil: I would have it raise an exception, though - there's a difference between "nothing implements my interface" and "I put in crap as an argument".  If you just return an empty enumerable, this won't be obvious to the developer.

Comment: @Reed.  Code has been updated to throw an exception if (!typeof(T).IsInterface), tested and working as expected.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can constrain the type to a specific interface, but not "any" arbitrary interface.

```
// This is allowable
public T MyFunction<T>() where T : IMyInterface { return null; }
```

This will let you pass any object which implements that specific interface.

---

Edit:

Given your goals, from the comments, I would personally probably just put in some runtime checking:

```
public IEnumerable<T> LoadInterfaceImplementations<T>()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (!type.IsInterface)
        throw new ArgumentException("The type must be an Interface");

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no way to constrain the type to interfaces only.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a specific interface.  You could create a base interface that all your other interfaces derive from and use that as the constraint.